# How can I refresh the whole page on link visit in NuxtJS?

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt project and for the SEO purpose, I need to reload the pages every time I do visit any page. 
Is there any way I can do it on `Routers`?

Currently, my app is with the default behavior of NUXT ***" renders only the required components on visit"***. But I need to completely reload the pages.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense. For seo it will follow link in HTML and it will be server rendered each time. What you trying to do is to spoil use experience

Comment: What is that "SEO purpose"?

Comment: Reference [DOC](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/$nuxt/#refreshing-page-data)

Answer (score 7):

Check this.

```
this.$nuxt.refresh()
```

Answer (score 4):

I do believe that reloading the page cleares (and re-initializes) your vuex store, if you are using that

I don't know how to reload the page but I have a few suggestions that you could test

**Suggestion 1**
Wrap your page with a `v-if`. Then it wont render until you visit it

```
<template>
  <app v-if="someBoolean">
     .
     .
  </app>
</template>
<scripts>
  export default {
    computed: {
      someBoolean () {
        return blabla 
      }
    }
  }
</scripts>
```

**Suggestion 2**

```
this.$forceUpdate();
```

**Suggestion 3**
Bind your component to a `key`

```
<template>
  <yourComponent :key="componentKey" />
</template>
```

And change that key whenever you need re-rendering

Answer (score 4):

Try: `window.location.reload(true)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to refresh the page manually you can call - `this.$router.app.refresh()`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but this solved it well, just watch changes in the $route() method then refresh appropriately in the `layouts/default.vue` file.

```
<template>
  <div>
     <Nuxt keep-alive />
  </div>
</template>

<scripts>
    export default {
        watch: {
            $route() {
                location.reload();
            },
        }
    }
</scripts>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout nuxtjs, bind key property of router view to fullPath which always change on router change. It help rerender router:

```
 <nuxt :key="$route.fullPath"></nuxt>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh every page you move to..
Just use regular anchor tag <a href="/myRoute">
instead of <nuxt-link to="/myRoute">

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
this.$router.go(0)

window.location.reload() causes error if it used inside html template, works only as method